# Script has an error while running the code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google Sheet App Script and trying to to create a IF condition with it but receiving an error.

I want to populate This `"Right"` result in Cell AO3

Your help will be appreciated

```
function myFunction() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DATA')
 var ss = sheet.getRange()

   if(ss.getRange("i3").getValue()!='' 
   && 
   ss.getRange("h3").getValue()!='')
   
   {

console.log("Right!");
  
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you get an error, always post the error message. It's the key to knowing what's wrong.

Comment: updated please have a look @Thomas

Comment: You didn't pass any parameters when calling `getRange()` (see the red squiggly line). It [requires a row and column](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)).

Comment: How to make a code with this  var range = ss.getRange(3, 35); @Thomas

Comment: @Learning there are 4 ways of requesting a range. All of them are in this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column . There are examples for each of them so you can play around.

Comment: I am trying to get what i want @Marios if you see the above my updated code i tried to do it with  Row and Column but tis still not working

Comment: @Learning you are again doing the issue `2` I mentioned in my answer... Also column `i` is not in the `43` position...but `9`. `ss.getRange(3,9)`

Comment: Oh @Marios thats the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues:

1. You didn't pass any parameters in the `getRange()` method.
2. Even if you did the first part correctly, in your code, `ss` is already a [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object because you already used `getRange(..)`. Therefore you **can't** use `getRange(..).getRange('i3')` twice.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DATA');
 if(ss.getRange('i3').getValue()!='' && ss.getRange("h3").getValue()!='') { 
      console.log("Right!");
     ss.getRange('ao3').setValue("Right!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Marios for the solution but how to paste console.log result in range AO3

Comment: @Learning answer updated. The value will be pasted only if it passes the `if` condition.

Comment: Yes @Marios well noted.